# Zozo tabs and ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have zozo tabs script and i want make ajax request at change tabs.
Here is my [preview](http://jsfiddle.net/RvWSX/3/)

Animation doesn't work here- i don't now why, but you can see javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        checkOrientation("vertical");

        var onSelect = function(event, item) {
console.log("Selected tab text: " + item.tab.text()); alert('dsadsa');
};

        var tabbedNav = $("#tabbed-nav").zozoTabs({
            orientation: "vertical",
            animation: { duration: 200 },                
            defaultTab: "tab1",
            effects: "slideD",
            easing: "easeOutQuad",
            select: onSelect
        });

        $("#ddl-orientation").bind("change", function (e) {
            var orientation = $(this).val();
            checkOrientation(orientation);
            tabbedNav.data('zozoTabs').setOptions({ "orientation": orientation });
        });

        $("#ddl-position").bind("change", function (e) {                
            tabbedNav.data('zozoTabs').setOptions({ "position": $(this).val() });
        });

        function checkOrientation(orientation) {
            jQuery('#ddl-position').children('option[data-orientation="h"]').attr('disabled', !(orientation === "horizontal"));
        }

    });
```

Apparently this animation is easy to use in ajax.

here is [documentation](http://docs.zozoui.com/tabs/)

I don't know well javascript and i don't have idea what i must do.

Could you show me where i must put code to active ajax ? simple alert message will by ok : ) I will be grateful too, if you tell me how return ajax request to content tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSelect(event,item)
{
    if(item.tab.text() == 'some tab name')
    {
        alert("i can rollerblade");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used 'select' attribute of zozo tabs but it never worked for me.
But I have found an alternative for it
Put a class or id in li.

```
$("li#123").live("click", function(e){

 if($(this).text() == 'some tab name')
    {
        alert("i can rollerblade");
        $.ajax({
        ..........
         });

    }
}
```